# Fill in website with excel file

Tags: excel, web

I've been asked to create a website. Before this one, everything was easy and simple html, add some pictures and mostly done in a few days. This time I've encountered a few new things and really need a push in the right direction.

I've got a list in Excel which contains over 500.000 items (vertically) and their attributes (horizontal)

E.g.

item att1 att2 att3 att4

item1 2_12v_yes

item2 1_***_*__**_no

item3 ***_*__*_*__*_*_**_0,5g

Not all items got the same attributes but all have some attributes. So I want to make one 'item page' and use this for all items. This way every page got the same layout but just different text and pictures.

So basically I'm looking for a way to read the excel file (or converted to other format?) from the website and use that data to fill in the pages for every item using one template.

E.g.

Item1 page

tekstxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

att1:  2

att2: 12

att3: yes

Item2 page:

tekstxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

att1: 1

att3: no

I do realise this isn't an easy question but haven't got a clue where to start.

Hope someone can push me in the right direction :)

Thanks,

Rick

Comment: Were you looking form something to generate page(s) from this data (which can be done tons of ways), or have the server read the sheet to generate pages (which will depend on the server), or want this to be done at the browser (in which case Javascript is probably called for)?

Comment: Uhm,.. Well as long as I don't have to type all those items and their attributes I don't care to be honest.

I made an app with some friends a while ago. We made a few views, game everything an id, made lists to place them in and all the information, text and pictures got in their through a server with excel files on it.

So basically wondering how to fill in a website page (since all item pages look the same) with information out of an excel file (or excel file converted to something else) cause otherwise I will be typing for the next 3-4 months :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be thinking in some programing languaje like php.  Wont be easy to load that amount of info 1 by 1 item. You can load external files as you said, but will need to know something of development. Only with HTML will be hard work to do.

Comment: What tool/program would you recommend to use then? There is tooooooo many to choose from.

Comment: How are you uploading the pictures ?  are you using only HTML ?  any Jquery or PHP ?  PHP offers the option of reading files.  PHP offers the option of DATA.  Thats why HTML is usually static content, everything about data need to be done manually.  PHP is dinamic DATA.  By other hand Jquery offers the option of AJAX, It can do the  DATA work loading what you need, need to learn a bit of it, It would save your time. And read about the LOAD()  function of Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Saving the spreadsheet in CSV (or some other simple text) format will make t a LOT easier to work with.